# how to get key in map and output of one key value is the input of next key in java

Tags: java

I wrote this code but i am not getting the right output.
`System.out.println(map.get(explain));` basically, my final output will be  the value of the explain key.
this is my code

```
package test;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = new String(
                "http://fts-master.intermesh.net:8020/solr/im-search/select?mc1=%2285665%22&mc3=%2285665A%22&mc4=%2285665B%22&mc5=%2285665LS%22&mc6=%2285665SS%22&mc7=%2285665P%22&mcHigh=%22825%2096447%22&mcHighA=%22825A%2096447A%22&mcHighB=%22825B%2096447B%22&q=shopping%20bags&qt=im.search&ps=2&rows=500&start=0&lat=0&lon=0&spellcheck=true&fq=CustTypeWt:(149%20179%20199%20699%201199%201299%201399%201499)%20AND%20isphoto:true&fq=mcatid:(1224%20825%2085665%2096468%203078%2073252%2096447%205502%20185408%2085676%2096463%20191641%2096472%20139933%20186677%2094993%2099531%2065430%20106446%20129653%2096488%2096478%205575)%20titlex:(%22imswshopbagimsw%22)&fq=-glusrid:(398689)&fq=attribs:(locprefglobal%20locprefnational%20locprefcity%20locprefunknown)&ql1=%22shopbagimsw%22&boost=map(query(%7B!dismax%20qf=mcatid%20v=$mc3%20pf=%22%22%7D),0,0,map(query(%7B!dismax%20qf=mcatid%20v=$mc4%20pf=%22%22%7D),0,0,map(query(%7B!dismax%20qf=mcatid%20q.op=OR%20v=$mcHighA%20pf=%22%22%7D),0,0,map(query(%7B!dismax%20qf=mcatid%20q.op=OR%20v=$mcHighB%20pf=%22%22%7D),0,0,map(query(%7B!dismax%20qf=mcatid%20v=$mc1%20pf=%22%22%7D),0,0,1,1.31%20),6.0),8.0),13.0),19.0)&boost=map(query(%7B!dismax%20qf=mcatid%20v=$mc7%20pf=%22%22%7D),0,0,1,1.2)&boost=map(query(%7B!dismax%20qf=mcatid%20v=$mc5%20pf=%22%22%7D),0,0,map(query(%7B!dismax%20qf=mcatid%20v=$mc6%20pf=%22%22%7D),0,0,1,1.2),1.2)&boost=map(query(%7B!dismax%20qf=titlex%20v=$ql1%20pf=%22%22%7D),0,0,1,1.22)&boost=productqualityscore&debugQuery=true&fq=displayid:15004840733");
        Map<String, Object> map = Utility.getResults(s);
        System.out.println(map);
        Set<String> keys = map.keySet();
        for (String response : keys) {
            System.out.println(map.get(response));
            {
                for (String debug : keys) {
                    System.out.println(map.get(debug));
                    {
                        for (String explain : keys) {
                            System.out.println(map.get(explain));
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please explain what you expect this code to do, and what it actually does, and why are you iterating over the same keyset in nested loops? On a separate note, don't use `new String(...)`. The literal is already a string, no need to create another copy. Nor is it necessary to start separate block scopes after `System.out.println`. It adds nothing of value here.

Comment: Please do not change question so significantly. Code is totally different from previous. Current answers are based on your original question/code and it is confusing

Comment: actually i have some other query about string extraction  and i can ask only one question in a day that's why i changed the previous code .so,sorry for instant change

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be in your below code. This code is not making much sense. Basically, this code is iterating over same set. Ex: if your "map" is {(1,a),(2,b)} and "keys" is {1,2}, your output will be aaabbb. Are you sure you want to do this?

```
for (String response : keys) {
        System.out.println(map.get(response));
        {
            for (String debug : keys) {
                System.out.println(map.get(debug));
                {
                    for (String explain : keys) {
                        System.out.println(map.get(explain));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

instead, you might want to do something like:

```
for (String response : keys) {
    String res = map.get(response);
    String debug = map.get(res)
    ... //any other operation you want to link with response object.

}
```

Or something like

```
for (String response : keys) {
    String res = map.get(response);
    Response resObj = new Response(res);
    Debug deb = resObj.getDebug(); //assuming debug is field in respose body.
    ... //any other operation you want to link with response object.

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to do something like this in place of the nested for-loops -

```
Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
Map<String, Object> debugMap = (Map<String, Object>) map.get("debug");
Map<String, Object> explainMap = (Map<String, Object>) map.get("explain");
Stream.of(explainMap.keySet().toString()).forEach(System.out::println);
```